# CAKEPHP - Using Session inside a custom component destroy SESSIOn

Tags: cakephp

I am trying to use a Session component inside a custom component, I called Myauth.
I use Myauth inside a controller by calling 
    var $components = array('Myauth');

In Myauth the code is :

```
 class MyauthComponent extends Object{
        function startup(&$controller)
        {
            $this->controller =& $controller;
    }
function createPerm ($key,$controller)
        {
            $a = "something";
    echo $this->controller->Session->write($key.'.Permission',$a);
            pr($_SESSION);
        }
```

The problem is that $_SESSION gets empty (if I do not call the write method, $_SESSION is filled with my values)

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There are few things. Remove the echo and replace the , with a . before the $a. So change this:

```
echo $this->controller->Session->write($key.'.Permission',$a);
```

to this

```
$this->controller->Session->write($key.'.Permission'.$a);
```

Do you need the period after the Permission? ($key.'.Permission.'.$a)

If you want to have something like: Key.Permission.Value, you need to add the period.

```
$this->controller->Session->write($key.'.Permission.'.$a);
```